# PyQGIS filter using date column

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS python console, I can run the following to extract the week number from date column. How can I use the same in qgsExpression as a where clause? Any other option is welcome as long as it uses PyQGIS. I intend to filter a vector layer in QGIS to return records that match a particular week.

```
for x in layers:
if x.name() == "test":
    idx = x.fieldNameIndex("date_from")
    values = x.uniqueValues( idx )
    b =values[0] 
    print b.weekNumber()
    b.weekNumber()[0]
```

This expression gives me an indication of the week number. Can I use QgsExpression like
 `expr = QgsExpression( "\"date_from.weekNumber()\" = 99"  )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following as a `QgsExpression` to check if a week number is, for example, 39:

```
expr = QgsExpression( ' week("date_from") = 39 '  )
```

Just as an example, the following code uses the above expression to find features which have a week number of 39. If one does then it's row number will be printed which could then be used for filtering:

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
for x in layers:
    if x.name() == "test":
        idx = x.fieldNameIndex("date_from")
        values = x.uniqueValues( idx )
        expr = QgsExpression( ' week("date_from") = 39 '  )    # Set week number to 39
        for f in x.getFeatures():
            f[idx] = expr.evaluate( f )
            if f[idx] == 1:    # Uses Boolean values (0 = False; 1 = True)
                print "row number: ", f.id()
```

*Note: The `date_from` field I used was a **Date-type** field, so the format was YYYY-MM-DD.*

Hope this helps!